# The definition of Normalized Standard Scores

Tags: normalization

I am studying a past psychology exam paper at university, and I came across this question.

```
The following type of test norms is an example of normalized standard scores:

 A. z-scores
 B. mental age scales
 C. stanine scale
 D. percentiles
```

I think there are two big issues here that is giving me a lot of confusion.

1. Aren't all 4 of these scales typically normally distributed? In that case `A. z-scores` would probably be correct, as one would expect it to always be normally distributed, right?
2. Isn't it that the word `normalized` (as quoted from the question) should be seen as an "action" that was performed on the data - which might have been skewed before? I imagine that if you group the data into percentiles you can regroup them into normal scores. In that case, the answer would be `D. percentiles`?

Comment: This looks like self-study to me. But here is one hint: $z$-scores aren't normally distributed unless the original data are. The calculation $z =$ (value $-$ mean) / SD gives whatever it gives, but doesn't imply or produce a normal distribution. The skewness and kurtosis of $z-$scores is exactly the same as that of the underlying distribution.

Comment: "Normalized" does not mean "normally distributed," nor does it refer to a process of removing skewness from data.  "Normalized" is a generic term that almost always refers to a process of *shifting* and *rescaling* data so the new data have a prespecified location and spread.  In some cases more complex operations may conducted for this "normalization." The correct answer would thus seem to depend on what the test creator had in mind and likely is not authoritatively answerable by anyone not privy to that information.